# Writing a regex for an Express route which has a variable number of parameters

Tags: regex, express

I'm building an API, and trying to allow the user to 'filter' the result set using any combination of parameters.

We have 2 cats, each with 4 properties: *name*, *age*, *sex* and *color*.

`cat1 = {'name': 'Fred', 'age': '10', 'sex': 'male', 'color': 'white'}`

`cat2 = {'name': 'Alex', 'age': '10', 'sex': 'male', 'color': 'black'}`

I'd like a **single** route to match any combination of the parameters the user chooses to apply to their search. For example, the route would match the following (as well as any other combination):

`router.get('/name/:name/age/:age/sex/:sex/color/:color', ...){}`

`router.get('/name/:name/age/:age/sex/:sex', ...){}`

`router.get('/age/:age/color/:color', ...){}`

Essentially, all parameters are optional.

I think regex is the best way to go - how can I do this?

Comment: Usually an API is very strict in the order of the parameters, if they are part of the address itself and not query parameters (`?name=Alex`). So, why do you want to do that..?

Comment: Can the parameters be in any order? `router.get('/name/:name/age/:age...` or `router.get('age/:age/name/:name...`

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to use a regular expression to parse the full URI and extract the search criteria. *Criteria order is free.*

To extract the value of a parameter, I use the following regular expression :

`\/`*paramName*`\/([^\/]+)(\/|$)`

---

**Explanation**

`\/`*paramName*`\/` : Match the given parameter name between slashes

`([^\/]+)` : Match anything except a slash (This is our value)

`(\/|$)` : Ends with a slash or end of line

---

Here is a working **JavaScript snippet** :

```js
/**
* Extract the value of a param inside a path
* Path format should match this pattern : /p1/p1value/p2/p2Value/pX/pXValue
* @param {string} path The path
* @param {string} param The param name
*/
function getParamValue(path, param) {
  var re = new RegExp('\/'+ param + '\/([^\/]+)(\/|$)');
  var matches = re.exec(path);
  if(matches && matches.length) {
    return matches[1];
  }
}

// Define possible criteria
var criteria = ['name', 'age', 'sex', 'color', 'dummy'];

// Let's play with some sample paths
var paths = [
  "/name/mcfly/age/42/sex/male/color/blue",
  "/sex/male/name/color/blue/mcfly/age/42",
  "/sex/male",
  "/color/black/name/kitty"
];

// For each path, display criteria and associated values
paths.forEach(function(path) {
  console.log("path=", path);
  criteria.forEach(function(criterion) {
    console.log(criterion + '=' + getParamValue(path, criterion));
  });
  console.log("------------------------");
});
```

---

In addition, here is a sample **Express** app :

**utils.js**

```
module.exports = {
    getParamValue: function (path, param) {
      var re = new RegExp('\/'+ param + '\/([^\/]+)(\/|$)');
      var matches = re.exec(path);
      if(matches && matches.length) {
        return matches[1];
      }
    }
}
```

**search-service.js**

```
var utils = require('./utils');

module.exports = {
    getSearchCriteria: function(path) {
        var criteria = [];

        ['name', 'age', 'sex', 'color'].forEach(function(criterion) {
            var value = utils.getParamValue(path, criterion);
            if(value) {
                criteria.push({"criterion": criterion, "value": value});
            }
        });

        return criteria;
    },

    search: function(criteria) {
        return "search using the following criteria", JSON.stringify(criteria, null, 2);
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var searchService = require('./search-service');

var port = 7357;

app.get('/api/search/*', function(req, res, next) {

    var criteria = searchService.getSearchCriteria(req.originalUrl);
    var result =   searchService.search(criteria);

    res.send("<!doctype html><html><body><pre>" + result + "</pre></body></html>");
});

// start server
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server listening on port %d', port);
});
```

Run `node app` then test some urls :

http://localhost:7357/api/search/name/mcfly/age/42/sex/male/color/blue

http://localhost:7357/api/search/sex/female/color/orange/name/judith/age/25

http://localhost:7357/api/search/color/green

and check page content

Comment: @callum-messiter if you're the one who upvoted this, don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work